# How to configure Firebase usage alerts?

Tags: firebase

We are planning to start using Firebase for a mobile React native application. I was wondering if there is a way to configure "alerts" that can send out an email to our admins when the usage crosses a certain threshold so we can switch from the free (Spark) plan to the Paid (Flame or Blaze) plan.

Also, if there are any references for best practices related to when to switch between plans, that would be great.

Thank you for your help.